# Listener gets fired only ONCE after adding all items in JCOMBOBOX though FireIntervalChanged is called for each item

Tags: java, actionlistener, jcombobox

```
combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Within actionPerformed/ItemStateChange");
        }   
   });
  System.out.println("Added items to combo");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        combo.addItem(i);
    }
```

Calling an addItem calls these methods internally

1) addElement

2)fireIntervalAdded

3)((ListDataListener)listeners[i+1]).intervalAdded(e);

4)intervalAdded calls ->SelectedItemChanged()

5) and finally stateChange is done.

So my question is while adding every item in combobox , Listener should be invoked. But listener is invoked only once. In internal implementation , they have used ListDataListener. How this listener knows that all elemnts have been added or "x" element is the last element...???

Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;


public class test {
    private static JComboBox combo;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        combo = new JComboBox<>();
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Within actionPerformed/ItemStateChange");

            }
        });
        System.out.println("Added items to combo");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            combo.addItem(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Removed Items from Combo");
        invokeRemove();
    }

    private static void invokeRemove() {
        combo.removeAllItems();

    }

}
```

Comment: You add listener **after** adding items

Comment: Sorry..I have changed it.. Pasted wrong.. But y it is being called only once?

Comment: Could you post SSCCE to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yeah.. I have posted .Its just a testcode that i was using to test addItems and removeAll's behaviour..

Comment: fireInterval is getting triggered  internally for each addItem. But its getting printed only twice. Once while adding and once while removing.

Answer (score 1):

For me the behaviour is correct. Adding something in the combobox does not change selection. So first time you added element selection becomes from `nothing` to the `first element` (0). After that you add multiple elements but 0 remains selected. And action is not triggered.

After removing all elements selection moves from `0` to `nothing` and the action is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. :) "Adding something in the combobox does not change selection". So when we add an item (For the first time it gets triggered and while removing once it gets triggered..) Can u explain where this happens internally ..?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your idea..I just now found the part where ItemState Change occurs when addItem is added.

**JCombo.class**

```
  protected void selectedItemChanged() {
    if (selectedItemReminder != null ) {
        fireItemStateChanged(new ItemEvent(this,ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED,
                                           selectedItemReminder,
                                           ItemEvent.DESELECTED));
    }

    // set the new selected item.
    selectedItemReminder = dataModel.getSelectedItem();

    if (selectedItemReminder != null ) {
        fireItemStateChanged(new ItemEvent(this,ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED,
                                           selectedItemReminder,
                                           ItemEvent.SELECTED));
    }
}
```

They have used ListDataListener . Adding  an ActionListener to the jcombo adds an ActionListener to the ListDatalistener's list. Whenever there occurs an item state change , listeners that are registered to ListDataListener gets notified. So i get the sysout in addActionListener.

This method is called in JCOMBOX constructor. This registers addActionListener to the ListDataListener.And Notification comes when item state changes.

```
  public void setModel(ComboBoxModel<E> aModel) {
    ComboBoxModel<E> oldModel = dataModel;
    if (oldModel != null) {
        oldModel.removeListDataListener(this);
    }
    dataModel = aModel;
    dataModel.addListDataListener(this); 

    // set the current selected item.
    selectedItemReminder = dataModel.getSelectedItem();

    firePropertyChange( "model", oldModel, dataModel);
}
```